# Cómo enviar parámetros por url en codeigniter 3?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

Necesito enviar un parámetro por url a una función a través de una ruta ya configurada, me explico, en el archivo application/config/routes.php tengo configuradas mis rutas, quiero configurar la siguiente `$route['leermensaje'] = 'citrabajadores/leermensaje';` para enviarle desde una vista mediante `href=""` pero no sé cómo hacerlo, al intentarlo me envía al error 404.
Adjunto el código de la vista de donde quiero enviar el parámetro...

```
                salida = '<h6 class="dropdown-header"> Mensajes </h6>'; 
                resp.map( (producto) => {
                    let text = producto.fecha_envio; const myArray = text.split("-"); let fecha = myArray[2] + "-" + myArray[1] + "-" + myArray[0];
/* En esta línea */ salida += '<a id="'+ producto.numero_web +'" href="<?= base_url();?>leermensaje/'+ producto.numero_web +'" class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" >';
                    salida +=       '<div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3">';
                    salida +=           '<img class="rounded-circle" src="<?= base_url();?>assets/img/undraw_profile_2.svg" alt="...">';
                    salida +=           '<div class="status-indicator"></div>';
                    salida +=       '</div>';
                    salida +=       '<div>';
                    salida +=           '<div class="text-truncate">'+ producto.mensaje +'</div>';
                    salida +=           '<div class="small text-gray-500">'+ producto.nombre +' '+ producto.apellido +'</div>';
                    salida +=           '<div class="small text-gray-500">'+ fecha +' a las '+ producto.hora_envio +'</div>';
                    salida +=       '</div>';
                    salida += '</a>';
                }); 
                $('#listamensajes').html(salida);
```

Comment: ¿Quieres enviar algo como url/leermensaje/id_producto?

Comment: Si estimado algo así

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar lo que comentas y recibir por GET debes decirle al *Route* que vas a recibir.

```
$route['leermensaje/(:num)'] = 'citrabajadores/leermensaje/$1';
```

De esta forma puedes recibir algo como *leermensaje/1* y el back recibirá en 1 como parámetro.

Te dejo la documentación official para que te guíes a futuro:

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

EDIT:

Para agregar más de 1 parámetro es el mismo principio:

```
$route['leermensaje/(:num)/(:num)'] = 'citrabajadores/leermensaje/$1/$2';
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigazo :D